# How to Create Dynamic Request Mapping based on Properties file in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a RESTApi Application using java SpringBoot.I stuck with a scenario suppose i have configure.properties file loaded with all the endpoints.

**configure.properties**

```
url1=/endpoint1
url2=/endpoint2
....
```

Now in controller class, I need to create @RequestMapping in such a way that whenever i add/delete endpoints from properties file then with only one method it adapts it. I no need to manually go in controller class file to do something.

**Controller.class**

```
@RestController
@GetMapping(...)
public void ping(){
...
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edited:
Just to clarify more I do not want to create separate methods for all endpoints and also in future if I add more endpoints in the properties file then that also should be handled by only a single method without modifying anything in controller class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on your requirement, but assuming you need to change the endpoint dynamically this might help you.

You can use placeholders, something like,

```
@RestController
@GetMapping("${url1}")
public void ping(){
...
}
//for using url1 from properties file
```

```
@RestController
@GetMapping("${url2}")
public void ping(){
...
}
//for using url2 from properties file.
```

However, you need to restart the application each time you need to change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify more I do not want to create separate methods for all endpoints and also in future if I add more endpoints in the properties file then that also should be handled by only a single method without modifying anything in controller class.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure if this can be achieved. But here is a hint you can try. 1. GetMapping takes value parameter which takes array initialiser. So you can try @GetMapping(value={"${url1}", "${url2}", "${url3}"}). 2. Also if you wish to have a constant base path for all of your dynamic endpoints then, you can try @GetMapping(value={"yourBasePathUrl/**"}). This  will map all the endpoints following the yourBasePathUrl to the single method you have.

Comment: Can it be done in loops?? Like inside for loop can we create requestmappings??